# Reporting insignificant results using mean ranks

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, reporting

I have a number of non-significant results from a Kruskal-Wallis test and wondering the best way to report them.

My independent variable is 3 categories:

Group A: Uses product A; 
Group B: Uses product B; 
Group C: Does not use either product.

The dependent variables are ordinal/Likert agreement scale.

Would it make sense to say while no statistical difference was found between Group A, Group B, and Group C, in many cases, Group A and Group B had higher mean ranks than Group C? For example, could I say something like: "A comparison of mean rank scores demonstrates that one of the two types of product users had higher mean rank scores than non-users on the following statements (S1, S2, S3...)?

Comment: What message are you trying to convey?  That you think the reader should attach any meaning to differences you have declared are not significant?

Comment: Thank you for posing the question. I can see how providing this information wouldn't be particularly useful to readers. Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at an effect size statistic that will be easy to interpret by your audience. Vargha and Delaney's A reports the probability of an observation in group 2 being greater than an observation in group 1.

Comment: Thank you! I found your explanation of Vargha and Delaney's A on your excellent website.  I am using Stata, so wondering if is there any way to run this test on Stata? I'm also still wondering: if I report the effect size for non-significant results, is that information even useful to include?  Many thanks!

Comment: VDA is used for the two-sample case, which I think would make sense for what you have asked.  VDA is easy to calculate from the U or W statistic from a Mann-Whitney or Wilcoxon test.  Instructions are in [this document](http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/Nonparametric-EffectSize.docx). *P = U/(n1 * n2) and U = W - n.smaller * (n.smaller +1) / 2*. If your data aren't too unwieldy, you could also run the following R code on [this site](https://rdrr.io/snippets/). `A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10); B = c(5,6,7,8,9,10); library(effsize); VD.A(B, A)`

Answer (score 1):

Answer from my comments.

One approach might be to report an effect size statistic. Vargha and Delaney's *A* reports the probability of an observation in one group being greater than an observation in the other group.  I think this will be relatively easy for your audience to interpret.  For more rigor, a confidence interval for the statistic can be reported. VDA is used for two groups.

VDA is easy to calculate from the U or W statistic from a Mann-Whitney or Wilcoxon test. Instructions are in [this document](http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/Nonparametric-EffectSize.docx).

```
P = U/(n1 * n2)
U = W - n.smaller * (n.smaller +1) / 2.
```

(Note: Oddly, it appears that the "W" that R reports is the same as *U*.)

If your data aren't too unwieldy, you could also run the following R code on [this site](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) or in R.

```
if(!require(effsize)){install.packages("effsize")}
A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10)
B = c(5,6,7,8,9,10)
library(effsize)
VD.A(B, A)

   ### Vargha and Delaney A
   ###
   ### A estimate: 0.75 (large)
```

Note that the `effsize` package will return a confidence interval for Cliff's *delta*, which is linearly related to VDA. [Package documentation is here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/effsize/versions/0.7.4/topics/cliff.delta).

```
cliff.delta(B, A)

    ### Cliff's Delta
    ### 
    ### delta estimate: 0.5 (large)
    ### 95 percent confidence interval:
    ###      lower     upper 
    ### -0.1213262 0.8398131
```

VDA = Cliff's *delta* / 2 + 0.5

So, converting the output for Cliff's *delta*, VDA = 0.75 (0.439, 0.920)